# Specific columns width of a MailItem Table in Outlook using VBA and HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, format

I copy a table from Excel to an Outlook mailitem.

I want to set specific columns width to the table in Outlook.

This is the result of the code.
[image]

In Outlook I manually Autofit contents, then set from column 4 to 8 to 2 cm, column 9 is 2,3 cm and last column (10) is 2,4 cm.
How can that be done with HTML? I can set a fixed size from column 1 to 3 since it will be always the same.

I would also like to know how to make listed rows. I tried to use a code, but it didn't work.

This is the expected result.
[image]

This is the current code in VBA:

```vb
Function HTMLTabelaEntrada() As String
    Dim EntradaRG As Range, PrimColuna As Range, i As Range, RowRG As Range, j As Range
    Dim Rows As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim NumColuna
    Dim str As String
    Rows = Folha1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1
    Folha1.Activate
    str = "<table>"
    
    Set PrimColuna = Range(Cells(1, eData), Cells(Rows, eData))
    
    For Each i In PrimColuna
    
        str = str & "<tr>"
        iRow = i.row
        Set RowRG = Union(Cells(iRow, eData), Cells(iRow, eeSku), Cells(iRow, eeDescrição), _
          Cells(iRow, eeCaixasCompletas), Cells(iRow, eeCuvetesCaixa), _
          Cells(iRow, eeCuvetesSoltas), Cells(iRow, eeCuvetesTotal), _
          Cells(iRow, eeCaixasEsperadas), Cells(iRow, eeValidade), Cells(iRow, eeNotas))
        For Each j In RowRG
            j.Select
            If i.row = 1 Then
                str = str & "<th>" & j.Value & "</th>"
            ElseIf j.column = eData And j.row <> 1 Then
                str = str & "<td>" & Format(j.Value, "dd/mmm") & "</td>"
            ElseIf j.column = eeCuvetesTotal And j.Value = 0 Then
                str = str & "<td>" & " " & "</td>"
            ElseIf j.column = eeDescrição And j.row <> 1 Then
                str = str & "<td style="" text-align:left"">" & j.Value & "</td style>" & "</td>"
            Else
                str = str & "<td>" & j.Value & "</td>"
            End If
        Next j
        str = str & "</tr>"
    Next i
    str = str & "</table>"
    HTMLTabelaEntrada = str
End Function
    
     
Function HeadHTMLTable()
            
    Dim str As String
                
    str = "<head><style>" & vbNewLine
    str = str & "p{font-family:Cambria;font-size:16px}" & vbNewLine
    str = str & "table{table-layout:fixed;font-family:cambria;font-size:16px;border: 1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:75%}" & vbNewLine
    str = str & "table th{text-align:center;padding: 6px 4px 6px 4px;border: 1px solid black}" & vbNewLine
    str = str & "table td{text-align:center;border:1px solid black; padding: 2px 4px}" & vbNewLine
    'str = str & "table tr:nth-child(odd) td {background-color:red}" & vbNewLine
    str = str & "</style></head><body>"
             
    HeadHTMLTable = str
        
End Function
```